# Appium: 504 error gateway timeout

Tags: appium

Appium launches the safari browser, clicks on Launch Safari Button and errors out

2016-09-22 19:57:32:206 - [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not navigate to webview! Err: 504 - 504 Gateway Timeout
Gateway Timeout

Server error - server 127.0.0.1 is unreachable at this moment.

Please retry the request or contact your administrator.

Environment

Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue:15.3
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: MAC
IOS Mobile platform: 9.2
Real device: Ipad Air
libimobiledevice : HEAD
Details

Link to Appium logs

https://gist.github.com/rjmadhu/c77fe1753af07c8bc337174fc5501d24

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your appium server and see if you are able to see the error again. Gist that has been posted cannot be seen any more.